# YouTube API JSON Feed not looping the video ID

Tags: jquery, api, mobile, youtube

Im trying to create a JSON feed of youtube videos in a jQuery mobile ui-block but each video has the same url so its pulling in the same ID for each video and cannot for the life of me figure it out! i have it online at - http://www.abbeyshruletidyvillages.ie/app/#videos.
Thanks 
Pierce

```
/
// Video YouTube JSON Feed
//
function listVideos(data) {
console.log(data);
var output='';
for (var i=0; i<data.feed.entry.length; i++) {

    // Title
    var title = data.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
    // Tumbnail
    var thumbnail = data.feed.entry[i].media$group.media$thumbnail[0].url;
    // Description
    var description = data.feed.entry[0].media$group.media$description.$t;
    // Video ID
    var id = data.feed.entry[0].id.$t.substring(39);

    var blocktype = ((i % 2) === 1) ? 'b' : 'a';
    output += '<a href="#videoplayer" data-transition-"fade" onclick="playVideo(' + id + '\',\'' + title + '\',\'' + escape(description) + '\')">';
    output += '<div class="ui-block-' + blocktype + '">';


    output += '<h3 class=""movivetitle">' + title + '</h3>';
    output += '<img src="' + thumbnail + '" alt="' + title + '" />';
    output += "</a>"
    output += "</div>";
    }
$('#videolist').html(output);
}

function playVideo(id, title, description) {
    var output ='<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ id +'?wmode=transparent&amp;HD=0&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;controls=1&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    output += '<h3>' + title + '</h3>';
    output += '<p>' + unescape(description) + '</p>';
    $('#myplayer').html(output);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this it works

var description = data.feed.entry[i].media$group.media$description.$t;

```
var id = data.feed.entry[i].id.$t.substring(39);
```